# Multicast not working on macvtap device

Tags: ipv6, vlan, bridge, qemu, multicast

I have a problem with my virtual network and IPv6 network discovery (multicast traffic).

(The setup might seem a little bit involved and I don't remember the exact reasons for every design decision. Nevertheless the network proved to be stable and maintainable. Still possible there's room for optimization and simplification.)

My setup is this:

- qemu/kvm host ("qemu") is running Debian 10; I'm using virt-manager for administration where possible- one VM ("fw") is running a virtualized firewall/router with Ubuntu 18.04- NIC of fw is connected to "Bridge br0: Host device eno1":

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.f44d306689b5   no      eno1
                            vnet0
                            vnet1
```

- inside of fw I have created several VLAN devices for my different subnets to be filtered by the firewall
- my other VM ("server") is connected to "Host device br0.10: macvtap (source mode: Bridge)" (br0.10 is the VLAN device for VLAN-id 10 on br0.
- I have configured a global unicast /64-subnet (from tunnelbroker.net) in which fw and server have an address of that subnet configured
- I could ping the link-local address of server from fw

The problem:

- I could not ping the global-unicast address of server from fw
- tcpdump on fw showed neighbor solicitations where going out, but no replies were coming in
- tcpdump on qemu on br0 also showed the neighbor solicitations and no replies
- (the workaround) switching macvtap0 to promiscous mode solved the problem. Neighbor solications where received by server and replied to.

My questions are: Why do I have to switch macvtap0 to promiscuous mode manually? Isnt't multicast a standard network feature that should work "out of the box" with a VM? (Or is my setup so untypical, that my use case is not covered?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer at Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/944678/how-to-configure-macvtap-to-let-it-pass-multicast-packet-correctly/1033768#1033768 I'll just copy `sourcejedi`'s answer here:

> libvirt's macvlan has gained support for multicast. Unfortunately it
> is disabled by the default setting `trustGuestRxFilters="no"`, and the
> documentation is not explicit that this breaks multicast. As you
> observed, breaking multicast also breaks IPv6.
>
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1035253#c15
>
> You may be able to work around this by manually setting
> `trustGuestRxFilters="yes"`. There is a limitation: "support depends on
> the guest network device model, as well as the type of connection on
> the host". "Currently it is only supported for the `virtio` device
> model, and for `macvtap` connections on the host".
>
> https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICS
>
> IMO the natural model would be to allow multicast by default. Blocking
> multicast reception, on a network you think you're directly connected
> to, is an unpleasant surprise. Especially since `macvtap` still seems to
> allow sending multicast packets (as well as spoofed MAC source
> addresses!).

Comment: My question would be a duplicate, but I think I cannot mark it as duplicate of a Superuser question.